# How to space out underscore ONLY in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking to space the underscores only in Visual Studio Code

I know there is letter-spacing, but that's all letter spacing, I just want the underscores to be "stylized" since I use the BEM nomenclature and it's a little easier to quickly identify double underscores.

Comment: Without messing with the `letterSpacing` config (which affects all characters as you mentioned) I would look into a more readable font. Many of the monospaced fonts already space underscores apart for this reason.